# Kotlin Multiplatform use with 3rd party dependency, like org.webrtc:google-webrtc

Tags: android, ios, kotlin, webrtc

I am investigating the Kotlin multiplatform approach. I have followed the provided examples (at https://play.kotlinlang.org/hands-on/Targeting%20iOS%20and%20Android%20with%20Kotlin%20Multiplatform/06_SettingUpKotlinFramework ) and with that I can produce both an Android and an iOS app. However I can not get it to work using 3rd party dependencies, or more specifically with web rtc (org.webrtc:google-webrtc)

In my source set for commonMain (Shared Code) the correct dependency seems to be set, however in the code in the CommonMain the import (import org.webrtc.voiceengine.*) is not recognised at all (In a standalone Android app it works fine), preventing me to figure out if it is going to work at all.

```
sourceSets["commonMain"].dependencies {
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common")
    implementation ("org.webrtc:google-webrtc:1.0.30039")
}
```

Should this approach work and I am doing something wrong? Or is Kotlin MPP not suitable (yet) to do something like this?